# cant traceroute rubygems.org but can access it from browser

Tags: networking, routing, traceroute

```
root@lzm:~# traceroute -nI 50.112.0.205
traceroute to 50.112.0.205 (50.112.0.205), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.30.139.193  1.626 ms  2.661 ms  3.654 ms
 2  216.221.156.81  0.359 ms  0.618 ms  0.581 ms
 3  89.149.184.109  40.953 ms  40.943 ms  40.918 ms
 4  77.67.68.162  40.892 ms  40.869 ms  41.189 ms
 5  205.251.225.162  72.881 ms  72.873 ms  72.801 ms
 6  205.251.232.90  48.752 ms  48.727 ms  48.481 ms
 7  205.251.232.151  48.850 ms  48.716 ms  48.759 ms
 8  205.251.232.169  48.801 ms  48.799 ms  48.758 ms
 9  50.112.0.205  49.061 ms  49.290 ms  49.258 ms
root@lzm:~# traceroute -nI 54.245.255.174                                                                                                
traceroute to 54.245.255.174 (54.245.255.174), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.30.139.193  102.061 ms  108.101 ms  116.718 ms
 2  216.221.156.81  0.360 ms  0.586 ms  0.545 ms
 3  89.149.184.189  40.760 ms  40.740 ms  40.715 ms
 4  77.67.68.162  40.941 ms  40.925 ms  40.902 ms
 5  205.251.225.164  40.880 ms  40.801 ms  40.775 ms
 6  205.251.232.92  57.931 ms  57.904 ms  57.714 ms
 7  205.251.232.157  48.559 ms  48.793 ms  48.765 ms
 8  205.251.232.169  48.735 ms  48.537 ms  48.501 ms
 9  50.112.0.205  48.946 ms  48.922 ms  49.234 ms
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
```

How to explain the above data? Is that mean the 54.245.255.174 was blocked on 50.112.0.205?

but 54.245.255.174 is rubygems.org and I can access it from browser.

Comment: Because they may be blocking ICMP echo requests/responses aka pings

Comment: @Ashtray sudo traceroute -nT rubygems.org works. Thanks

Comment: @raykin, look in the `man traceroute` what does `-T` flag give you. It sends `TCP SYN` probes instead of ICMP. `-n` just prevents reverse DNS queries happening and just spits out addresses